# Анонимные классы в c++

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, объявление

Этот код вполне себе нормально компилируется.

```
class 
{ 
   public:
   //...
} anonymous;
```

Зачем и для каких целей применяются неименованные классы?

Comment: [Это же на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10072208/2076787).

Comment: @D-side и ? я видел этот вопрос ...

Comment: Ну, там есть несколько примеров. А ссылку я оставил, чтобы кто-нибудь (может даже вы) перевёл ответы оттуда на русский язык сюда.

Comment: Это пережиток С, не более того.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала хочу обратить ваше внимание, что в C++ нет **анонимных классов** с ключевыми словами `class` или `struct`. Вы путаете понятия **безымянного класса** и **анонимного класса**. Эти понятия различны и имеют разный семантический смысл. В своем вопросе вы ведете речь именно про **безымянные классы**.

Определения именованных классов определяют именованные типы. Используя это имя вы явно можете объявлять члены такого класса, в объявлении которых присутствует спецификатор типа класса, объекты этого типа или, например, параметры функций. Кроме того, если имя имеет внешнее связывание, то оно будет означать одну и ту же сущность в разных единицах компиляции, если включить объявление этого имени в эти единицы компиляции.

В безымянном классе невозможно, например, объявить конструкторы, деструктор, операторы, которые имеют тип возвращаемого значения или типы параметров, включающие в себя имя класса.

Вы также, например, не можете объявлять члены данных класса, которые являются указателями или ссылками на объекты класса.

В безымянном классе не разрешается объявлять статические члены данных класса.

Из стандарта C++ (9.4.2 Static data members)

> 4 [ Note: There shall be exactly one definition of a static data
>   member that is odr-used (3.2) in a program; no diagnostic is required.
>   —end note ] **Unnamed classes and classes contained directly or
>   indirectly within unnamed classes shall not contain static data
>   members.**

Например, как объявить узел списка, если вы не можете в определении этого узла объявить член данных, являющийся указателем на следующий или предыдущий узел?

Так что возможности безымянных классов очень ограничены.

Безымянные классы обычно используются как вложенные классы других классов или как локальные классы, когда введенный таким образом безымянный тип класса не требуется за пределами той области видимости, где этот безымянный класс определен.

Comment: эти возможности ограничены только из за того что у класса нет имени ?

Comment: @ampawd Да. Пока имя класса не объявлено, или его нельзя вывести из какого-то выражения, уже после определения безымянного класса то оно недоступно в программе, а, следовательно, вы не можете его использовать в объявлениях.

Comment: А что тогда такое *анонимный класс* и чем он отличается от *безымянного*?

Comment: @avp Вы можете задать отдельно такой вопрос и, надеюсь, получить на него ответ.:)

Comment: @avp вот тоже хотел спросить ))

Comment: @ampawd Так спрашивайте!:)

Comment: Ну вот Вас и спросили.

Comment: @avp Это комментарий, а не вопрос.:)

Comment: комментарий в виде вопроса )

Comment: @ampawd Я считаю, что это заслуживает отдельного вопроса, чтобы не было не правильных ответов таких, как второй здесь ответ.:)

Comment: OK, [вот оформил как вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597439/232)

Comment: Ещё вопорс по этому ответу: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597980/178988 - реальность с ним не сходится...

Answer (score 3):

Эта возможность оставлена ради совместимости со старым (C без плюсов кодом). 
В C безымянные и именованные структуры почти равноценны, поэтому в большом объеме кода применяется: `tyedef struct { int a; int b; } my_type;` (чтобы можно было писать `my_type` вместо `struct my_type` в точке использования типа. 
В C++ безымянные классы не имеют практического применения.

Comment: Безымянная структура и анонимная структура - это разные понятия. В C++ нет анонимных структур.

Comment: О какой совместимости с Си может идти речь, если в нем нет такого слова -- `class`? (а вот `struct` есть в обоих)

Comment: @avp В C++ class и struct - практически синонимы. Все возможности, разрешенные для struct, резрешены и для class.