# Чем в C++ отличаются анонимный и безымянный классы?

Tags: c++, классы

Вопрос в догонку к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597350/232) для уточнения [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597388/232)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, следует сначала обратиться к стандарту языка C, где было введено понятие анонимных структур и анонимных объединений.

В стандарте C 2011 анонимные структуры и анонимные объединения определяются следющим образом (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 13 An **unnamed member** of structure type with no tag is called an
>   **anonymous structure**; an **unnamed member** of union type with no tag is
>   called an **anonymous union**. The members of an anonymous structure or
>   union are considered to be members of the containing structure or
>   union. This applies recursively if the containing structure or union
>   is also anonymous.

Как видно из данного определения, не каждая безымянная структура или безымянное объединение являются анонимными. Только безымянные структуры и безымянные объединения, которые являются членами других структур или объединений являются анонимными.

В C++ нет анонимных классов, то есть классов, объявленных с ключевым словом `struct` или `class`, но есть анонимные объединения, которые определяются следующим образом (Стандврт С++, раздел 9.5 Unions)

> 5 A union of the form

```
union { member-specification } ;
```

> is called an **anonymous union**; it defines **an unnamed object of
>   unnamed type**. The member-specification of an anonymous union shall
>   only define non-static data members. [ Note: Nested types and
>   functions cannot be declared within an anonymous union. —end note ]
>   The names of the members of an anonymous union shall be distinct from
>   the names of any other entity in the scope in which the anonymous
>   union is declared. For the purpose of name lookup, after the anonymous
>   union definition, the members of the anonymous union are considered to
>   have been defined in the scope in which the anonymous union is
>   declared. [ Example:

```
void f() {
union { int a; const char* p; };
a = 1;
p = "Jennifer";
}
```

> Here a and p are used like ordinary (nonmember) variables, but since
>   they are union members they have the same address. —end example ]

Как видно из этого определения, понятие анонимного объединения в C++ отличается от соответствующего определения анонимного объединения в C. В C++ вы можете объявлять анонимное объединение вне какой-либо структуры или объединения.

Кто более детально интересуется данным вопросом, может также просмотреть открытую мною тему на [isocpp.org](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/ZIVHmLqGqaY)

Comment: Т.е., если коротко, то *анонимных классов* в C++ нет. Правильно?

Comment: @avp Классы определяются с ключевыми словами class, struct и union. В C++ нет анонимных классов  объявленных с ключевыми словами class или struct, но есть анонимные объединения, то есть классы, объявленные с ключевым словом union.

Comment: @avp Можно уверенно сказать, что в C++ нет анонимных структур.

Comment: Интересно. Наверное g++ -std=c++11 это не совсем С++, поскольку вот такую структуру `struct {
  int x, y;
  struct {
    int a, b;
  } p;
} p;` он вполне принимает (так же как и gcc (что вполне ожидаемо))

Comment: @avp У вас здесь нет анонимной структуры. Есть безымянная вложенная структура и соответствующий объект данной структуры с именем p. Чтобы получить анонимную структуру, как оно определено в C,, вы должны убрать определение объекта, а оставить только определение самой структуры. Кроме того многие компиляторы имеют собственные нестандартные расширения языка.

Comment: @avp Смысл анонимной структуры состоит в том, что ее члены становятся членами охватывающей структуры. Это не просто объявление безымянной структуры внутри другой структуры.

Comment: Тогда не понимаю текста ответа. Уточните более явно (можно без ссылок на стандарты, но ;желательно с примером кода (собственно код это и есть то, что реально существует)), что такое анонимная структура (и класс, если такое существует). Кстати, если заменить struct на class и прописать все members public, то в g++ тоже работает.

Comment: @avp Если брать ваш пример, то согласно стандарту C внутренняя безымянная структура struct { int x, y; struct { int a, b; }; } p; является анонимной. Ее члены a и b являются членами данных внешней безымянной структуры. Поэтому вы можете написать, например, p.a = 10;  Некоторые С++ компиляторы это также разрешают делать,  хотя в стандарте C++ об этом ни слова не говорится.

Comment: Перечитал внимательней. Я наконец-то правильно понимаю, что в С++ есть только **анонимные union** (как в Вашем примере, причем в такой форме они в Си недопустимы), а все class/struct без имени независимо от уровня вложенности называются безымянными?

Comment: @avp По крайней мере согласно стандарту C++ есть только анонимные объединения, и дается определение этого термина. Что касается классов, объявленных с ключевыми словами struct и class, то понятие анонимного класса или структуры отсутствует. Поэтому C++ не должен члены данных безымянных структур, которые (то есть структуры) при этом не определяют объект, как члены охватывающей структуры. Однако некоторые компиляторы это допускают. Я уже задал соответствующий вопрос на isocpp.org, и жду, что там скажут.

Comment: Отлично, значит разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: @avp Я как дождусь ответа на isocpp.org, то дам вам знать.:)