# Чего нельзя сделать в безымянном классе?

Tags: c++

Вопрос связан с [этим ответом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597388/178988), где говорится:

> В безымянном классе невозможно, например, объявить конструкторы, деструктор, операторы, которые имеют тип возвращаемого значения или типы параметров, включающие в себя имя класса.
>
> Вы также, например, не можете объявлять члены данных класса, которые являются указателями или ссылками на объекты класса.
>
> В безымянном классе не разрешается объявлять статические члены данных класса.

Однако, если попробовать, то всё оказывается несколько не так:

http://ideone.com/FzRqOF

Вариант с аргументом лишний - я его ещё не допилил.
Но возвращаемое значение и статический метод явно работают.

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
class
{
public:
    auto operator + () -> decltype(*this)
    {
        cout << "Unary plus\n";
        return *this;
    }
 
    static void do_smth()
    {
        cout << "Static method\n";
    }
 
    void test(auto obj)
    {
        cout << "Argument\n";
    }
} smth;
 
int main()
{
    +smth;
    decltype(smth) b;
    +b;
    decltype(b)::do_smth();
    smth.test(b);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Статическое поле получается только при использовании `-fpermissive`, но вполне работает:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vuGA7yZvmS2ltLiM

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class
{
public:
    static int value;
} smth;

int decltype(smth)::value = 10;

int main()
{
    cout << decltype(smth)::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В примере класса нет ни явно объявленных конструкторов, ни деструкторов.

В классе нет объявлений нестатических членов данных класса.

В классе нет объявлений статических членов данных класса.

Можно объявлять тип возвращаемого значения у операторов с помощью указателя `this`, при условии, что операторы являются членами класса, а не дружественными функциями, но возникнут сложности с объявлением параметров операторов.

Что касается статических методов, то в цитате, которую вы привели, ничего про них не говорится. Тем не менее возникает вопрос, как объявить тип класса в качестве возвращаемого типа статических функций, когда они не имеют доступа к `this`?

Что касается данного объявления

```
void test(auto obj)
{
    cout << "Argument\n";
}
```

то оно является некорректным с точки зрения стандарта C++.

Компиляторы могут иметь собственные расширения языка, которые не соответствуют стандарту C++, либо иметь собственные баги.:)

Comment: Да, про статические не так понял. Я почему-то подумал, что вообще статического ничего нельзя, а оказывается, только поля. А с нестатическими что не так? Их-то точно можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Может быть я что-то пропустил, но в вашем примере нет объявлений нестатических членов класса имеющих спецификатор типа класса. Как это сделать?

Comment: Это я ещё не придумал. Проблема именно в том, что нельзя, или в том, что это запрещено? Почему запрещены статические поля? `prog.cpp:19:13: error: static data member '<anonymous class>::value' in unnamed class [-fpermissive]
  static int value;`

Comment: @Qwertiy Определение статического члена данных включает  в себя квалифицированное имя, то есть имя класса. Поэтому и запретили.

Comment: @Qwertiy, явно стандартом запрещены только статические члены, всё остальное не запрещено, Но, вряд ли получится это использоваться, всё равно. Почему запрещены статические члены? Потому что статический член должен быть определён вне класса, а определить его не получится, т.к. нет имени. При определённых условиях не нужно определять константы, но если они odr-used, то их определение становится необходимым и получаем ту же проблемы. Поэтому, видимо, их просто взяли и запретили, чтобы не морочить голову.

Comment: @ixSci, при желании (`-fpermissive`) всё получается: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vuGA7yZvmS2ltLiM

Comment: @Qwertiy, при каком желании? Вы просто заткнули компилятор и «вырубили» стандарт. Хотя я вынужден согласиться, что с `decltype` это правило, в целом, можно обходить.

Comment: @ixSci, я не про то, что я вырубил стандарт, а про то, что код-то получился работающим. Т. е. кроме формального требования стандарта "статические поля нельзя", сейчас нет фактических причин их запрещать. Возможно, это правило устарело с обновлением стандарта?

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен. Можно этот вопрос поднять в какой-нибудь группе оп стандарту. Это, конечно, минорное изменение, но его можно внести.