# Анонимный объект

Tags: c++

Что такое анонимный объект в С++?

Этот вопрос вводит меня в некоторое замешательство. Ведь по данному запросу гугл говорит, что анонимных объектов в С++ нет. Например, [анонимные классы в c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597350/).
И тут же, цитата с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293608.aspx):

> Лямбда-выражение (или просто *лямбда*) в C++11 — это удобный способ определения анонимного объекта-функции.

Comment: А вы путаете классы и объекты. У объектов имена вообще не предусмотрены.

Comment: @VTT а не подскажете где почитать по этому вопросу. Ибо судя по всему я совершенно запутался.

Comment: Классы - это типы (у них может быть имя данное пользователем, или они могут быть анонимными). Анонимные - это означает что имя у них вообще-то тоже есть (генерируется компилятором), но оно неизвестно пользователю и обратится к ним по имени нельзя. Объекты - это экземпляры какого-то типа (имен у них нет). Имя может быть у переменной, но не у объекта который хранится в этой переменной.

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен без контекста. Откуда вы изначально взяли этот термин -"анонимный объект"? Приведите полный контекст, тогда станет понятно о чем шла речь.

Comment: @AnT Лямбда-выражение (или просто лямбда) в C++11 — это удобный способ определения анонимного объекта-функции. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293608.aspx

Comment: В такой ситуации речь идет просто о временном объекте, как например `std::string("hello")`. Временный объект не имеет имени. Назвать его "безымянным", как мне кажется, было бы более уместно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, далее представлено не то, что вам нужно, но пройдусь по терминологии.

Непосредственно термина "анонимный объект" в C++ нет. Но есть "безымянный объект" (unnamed object). Данный термин в таком виде встречается в черновике стандарта n4750 всего лишь раз в разделе про "анонимные объединения" (anonymous unions) 12.3.1/1:

> A union of the form  `union { member-specification } ;`
>   is called an anonymous union; it defines an unnamed type and **an 
>   unnamed object** of that type called an anonymous union object.

Пример оттуда же с моими комментариями:

```
void f() {
    union { int a; const char* p; };  // определяется безымянный объект типа объединение 
    a = 1;  // несмотря на то, что `a` и `p` используются как обычные переменные ...
    p = "Jennifer"; // ... они, тем не менее, являются членами безымянного объекта
}
```

Но есть и другие ситуации, например, безымянный объект можно получить, вызвав конструктор вида `T()` или вызвав функцию, возвращающую некий тип.

```
struct T() {};
T f() { T t; return t; }

T(); // создаёт безымянный объект
f(); // возвращает безымянный объект
```

Создание объекта через `new T` - это то же самое, что `T()`, только с размещением в куче, а не на стеке. И бесконечным временем жизни, ведь если для указателя, который вернул `new` не вызвать `delete`, мы получим утечку памяти. Безымянный объект, созданный на стеке, будет разрушен после ближайшей `;`.

Comment: И если я вас понял то, вот в таком примере объекты тоже являются безымянными  ideone.com/HRN44x  Но вместе с этим они имеют имя типа. Но если с первым примером все ясно, объединение не имеет типа и имени  то со вторым я не понимаю

Comment: @Nik добавил в ответ про `new`.

Answer (score 0):

### Скорее всего, речь идёт об rvalue

В языке c++ есть понятие lvalue и rvalue. Если совсем просто, lvalue это нечто, имеющее имя, а значит это "нечно" может быть слева в операторе присваивания, например:

```
int x;
x = 10;
```

Здесь объект x это lvalue, и мы можем присваивать "в него". Он также имеет имя "x", при этом не следует путать имя (в данном случае "x") и значение (сразу после определения оно скорее всего не определено, после присвоения значение будет 10). Обратите внимание, что "имя", о котором идёт речь, присутствует только на этапе компиляции. Также наличие имени обязывает разместить компилятор в какой-нибудь памяти, и значит, имеет смысл понятие адреса этого объекта (проще говоря, указатель).

Насчёт rvalue , тут всё похоже. Объект, не имеющий имени, это rvalue, пример:

```
int x;
x = 10;
```

Здесь 10 это rvalue типа int, если мы попытаемся в него присвоить что-нибудь: `10 = x;` , то получим ошибку компиляции. Rvalue могут быть "справа" в операторе присваивания, но не могут быть слева. Объект rvalue существует, но его адрес не имеет смысла (может вообще не существовать, потому что, к примеру, компилятор может его разместить в регистре, или вообще заоптимизировать).

Теперь насчёт функций. В языке Си, и в C++ до 11 стандарта, если вам была необходима некоторая функция, вы обязательно объявляли её прототип, и описание. В прототипе вы давали функции имя. Это аналог lvalue для функций, у вас есть функция с конкретным наименованием. С 11 стандарта появилась возможность создавать лямбда-функции, это функции, не имеющие имени, их можно использовать в аргументах других функций, передавая в качестве указателя на функцию. Получается, что лямбда-функция это анонимная, безымянная функция.

**Подробнее:**

1. [Про lvalue и rvalue](https://habr.com/post/348198/)
2. [Анонимная функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
3. [Лямбда-функции в C++](https://habr.com/post/66021/)
4. [Про лямбда-функции на cppreference](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Про r/l-value есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863439/176217) здесь.